# Generate URL based on title in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. Please help. I have 2 fields in model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :url, :description
end
```

After user enters the title, we need to auto populate the url form field by changing the following in title

1. remove all special characters from title
2. replace spaces with dash "-"
3. downcase

Then user can update the url to customize it further. Finally, when he clicks on "Create Article" button, we need to check the above 3 conditions again to validate.

I am using Rails 3.2.6

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that its a web app and the user is give a form with two textboxes where he can enter the title and url.
You can use javascript to auto generate the url in the textbox, where user can customize it and save.

Comment: Yes, there are two fields in the form for title and URL. In future, we want the auto generated URL to be checked for it's uniqueness by going to DB. So, I prefer all these functionality in rails side. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to make a ajax call to the server to generate the url based on the title entered and populate the url textbox.